# How to use a template html in different folder on Google App Engine python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, templates

I am trying to use a templated html file in a different folder on python and I am running into file not found error. For example,

```
index_path = os.path.join (os.path.join(os.path.dirname( __file__ ), '..', 'html'), 'index.html')
```

index.html is in html folder. My python handler code is in handlers folder.

```
.
├── app.yaml
├── handlers
├── html
```

How does the project structure look like when it is deployed in Google App Engine?

*Note*: I am using:

```
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
template.render(index_path, {})
```

I modified the code based on suggestions below, still no luck:

**handlers/index.py:**

```
jinja_environment = jinja2.Environment(
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname('html')))

index_file = 'index.html'
template = jinja_environment.get_template(index_file)
content = template.render({})

self.response.out.write(content)
```

**html/index.html:**

**From app.yaml:**

```
libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

Comment: What does `print(index_path)` give you?

Comment: something like ~/handlers/../html/portal.html

Comment: What templating system are you using? In Jinja2, the templating framework that comes with GAE, one doesn't usually build a complete file path, but rather prep a loader. What operation are you doing on index_path to get a "file not found error"?

Comment: I am using the default templates from webapp:

from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
template.render(index_path, template_values)

Comment: *something like `~/handlers/../html/portal.html`* is not valid for a deployed app because the application does not run out of the user's home directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferred way of rendering templates in GAE is to use Jinja2. Jinja2 makes use of [loaders](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#loaders).

> Loaders are responsible for loading templates from a resource such as
>   the file system

You'll want to modify `app.yaml` so your application has access to Jinja2.

```
libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

then prep a template environment and a loader to help get templates from your `html` folder

```
import jinja2

env = jinja2.Environment(loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader('html'))

template = env.get_template('index.html')
...
template.render(template_values)
```

---

EDIT :

Make the handlers folder a package by adding a `__init__.py`. With a dir structure such as:

```
.
├── app.yaml
├── handlers
│   ├── hello.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── html
    └── index.html
```

Then in the `handlers` section of `app.yaml` something akin to the following should do:

```
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: handlers.hello.app # with app defined in hello.py
...
libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It doesn't work. html folder is one level up from the handlers folder where my .py is located.

Comment: What are the contents of the handler section in your `app.yaml`, especially the script that is runs your app to render your templates?

Comment: @ssk Not all the info but anyway I've updated the answer to show what I mean by the `handlers` section of `app.yaml`.

Comment: ... and do not use `os.path.dirname`, just `'html'`